# Force different characters at different positions

Tags: javascript, html, input, numerical, alphabetical

I'm currently working on a project in which I need to fetch street/city details from a DB using a zipcode. Dutch zipcodes use a "1111 AA" format, I would like to have this entered in a single input field while forcing the first four characters to be numeric and the last two to be alphabetical.

I've been googling this quite a bit, have found ways to force either one, but none to combine it into a single input field and I don't seem to be crafty enough to combine them myself.

Thank you.

Comment: You should probably learn about *regular expressions*.

Answer (score 1):

We use this in alot of sites, especially for phone #s

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

This is finally a question where **regular expressions** are a suitable solution.

Try this:

```
var zip = "1111 AA"
var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{4}\\s?[A-Z]{2}$");
regex.test(zip);
```

Note that this will not allow lowercase characters, and will allow the zipcode without whitespace (like this: 1111AA). Try some googling to find out how to allow or disallow those.

Comment: Aye, you should use that. Google RegEx if you don't know how to use it.

Comment: the whitespace thing really isn't a problem, I already made it forgiving so either 1111 XX could be entered of 1111XX.


`$zipCode = $_GET["q"];
$count = substr_count($zipCode, ' ');

if ($count == '0') {
$zip = str_split($zipCode, 4);
$zipCode = $zip[0].' '.$zip[1];
}`

But I don't just want to check the value to be the right format, I wasnt to physically disable them from using alphabetical characters for the first four and numerical for the the last two.

Answer (score 0):

To handle the specific pattern you entered, try something like this in the javascript function  that validates form input:

```
var pattern = new RexExp( '[0-9]{4} [A-Z]{2}' );
if( inputFieldValue.search( pattern ) == -1 )
{
    // throw error condition.
}
else
{
    // The pattern matched. Continue on.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new html5 [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input) attribute for that:

```
<form>
   <input name="zipcode" type="text" pattern="\d{4}\s?[A-Z]{2}" length="7" />      
   <input type="submit" />
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

If the attribute isn't supported, you fall back to a javascript solution, checking the input field with a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) before submit like the following:

```
var pattern = /[0-9]{4}\s?[A-Z]{2}/;
string.match(pattern);
```

Take a look at the **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/buVpn/)**.